# Matix Exponential Layer (Custom: Keras in R)

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to make a layer in Keras (R) which [(matrix) exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) a layer of shape (d,d).

*ie.: Input to layer is a dxd matrix and the output is a dxd matrix which is the (matrix) exponential of the input matrix.*

**What I've Implemented to Date:**

Here's what I've done (its a degree 4 approximation because I'm also not sure how to get the [tensorflow matrix exponential command](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/expm) working in Keras):

```
  # Matrix Exponential
Matrix_Exp<- R6::R6Class("KerasLayer",

                         inherit = KerasLayer,

                         public = list(

                           call = function(x, mask = NULL) {
                             # Initialize Tenor-like Object -> Tensor Objects
                             ord0 = k_eye((k_shape(x)[1]))
                         ord1 = x
                         ord2 = (1/2)*k_dot(x,x) # note x is square so this works
                         ord3 = (1/6)*k_dot(x,ord2)
                         ord4 = (1/24)*k_dot(x,ord3)
                          ord0+ord1+ord2 +ord3+ord4
                           },

                           compute_output_shape = function(input_shape) {
                             c(d,d)
                           }
                         )
)
# Create layer wrapper function
layer_Matrix_Exp <- function(object) {
  create_layer(Matrix_Exp, object)
}
```

I'm plugging a model with this summary into the custom layer:

```
Model: "sequential_32"
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                                                            Output Shape                                                    Param #                  
=================================================================================================================================================================
dense_63 (Dense)                                                        (None, 100)                                                     400                      
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_64 (Dense)                                                        (None, 4)                                                       404                      
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_10 (Reshape)                                                    (None, 2, 2)                                                    0                        
=================================================================================================================================================================
Total params: 804
Trainable params: 804
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

**Problem/Error:**

But I run into this error when passing `layers_NE %>% layer_Matrix_Exp`

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function wrap_fn.<locals>.fn at 0x7fbdd0cf2b90> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: Evaluation error: object 'size' not found.
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  RuntimeError: in converted code:

    /scratch/users/BIM/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/keras/python/kerastools/layer.py:30 call  *
        return self.r_call(inputs, mask)
    <string>:4 fn

    /scratch/users/BIM/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/reticulate/python/rpytools/call.py:21 python_function
        raise RuntimeError(res[kErrorKey])

    RuntimeError: Evaluation error: object 'size' not found.
```

**Note:**

- The problem is coming from the identity part but I don't know how to fix this.

**Question:**

- How to fix error.
- How to replace the order 4 (manual) approximation to the matrix exponential with the keras equivalent to the [tensorflow matrix exponential command](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/expm).

Thanks in advance.